# Need to format PDF file

Tags: pdf, conversion, format, quickbooks

I have a PDF file that contains a customer list from the program CF Data Systems: Structure.

I need to import this customer data into QuickBooks, but the way QuickBooks imports requires it to be preformatted as cleanly as possible.

The problem I have is that the PDF file has customer data on multiple lines. Best case scenario, the data is supposed to be like the following:

```
CUST #     NAME          ADDRESS                       PHONE            FAX          . . . ETC.
00001      JOHN SMITH    1 MAIN ST., WORCESTER, MA     555-555-5555     555-555-6666
```

So essentially it has to be in 1 line. The problem is their customer data is on multiple lines, and each customer #/name has varying lines of data. For instance, the address data is split up onto 3 lines and the customer name is beneath the customer #.

I can manually move/edit the data but there are over 2000 customers. A macro is not usable because each line/customer has such varying data and the amount of lines used.

Is there a way I can import this data easier into QuickBooks?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Converting pdf to another file format or formatting the converted file so you can import it to quickbooks?

Comment: Formatting the PDF either with Acrobat, or formatting the Excel document we have of the same info to be imported into QuickBooks. I know in QB you can do a fixed width or delimited format, but neither of these work because of the way the data is presented to me.

Comment: If you have the possibility to use an Excel document instead of a pdf, do it. It is much better suited. Try exporting it as a csv and importing it as the [official support](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/HOW12247) proposes (maybe you can even import the Excel file directly). If it does not work specify what exactly fails, what you have tried and ask a separate question (since it is unrelated to pdf then).